How to add a custom column to admin user grid?
I am new to Magento and I am stuck with adding a column to a grid. I have created a new module (StoreAdmin) to assign every admin to specific store (for some reasons I have been asked to do so). I have added a new column (store_id) to the table admin_user using an UpgradeSchema class. I also have added a dropdown field in the users edit form populated with the available stores and it works (assigning the store id to the admin).
Now I am trying to add a new column to the admin users grid but it does not appear there. I wonder what I am missing. I am not even sure if I am on the right track to do it.
di.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\User\Block\User\Edit\Tab\Main"
                type="Vendor\StoreAdmin\Block\Edit\Tab\Main"/>
    <type name="Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User\Collection">
        <plugin name="add_store_id_column"
                type="Vendor\StoreAdmin\Plugin\AddStoreIdColumn"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\User\Model\User">
        <plugin name="vendor_storeadmin_save_store_id"
                type="Vendor\StoreAdmin\Plugin\AdminUserSaveStoreId"/>
    </type>
</config>

AddStoreIdColumn.php:
<?php

namespace Vendor\StoreAdmin\Plugin;

use Magento\User\Model\ResourceModel\User\Collection;

class AddStoreIdColumn
{
    /**
     * Add store_id to the grid collection
     *
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @return void
     */
    public function beforeLoad(Collection $collection)
    {
        $collection->getSelect()->columns(['store_id' => 'main_table.store_id']);
    }
}


It seems like you've already made progress by adding the store_id column to the admin_user table and implementing the dropdown in the user edit form to assign a store to the admin. However, adding a column to the grid may not be necessary if your goal is to manage users based on specific stores. This functionality can typically be handled through Magento's role-based permissions system.
You can set up roles for specific stores and assign them to users. This way, the grid will display users based on their roles and associated permissions, without the need for additional customization. If the requirement explicitly needs the store_id column in the grid, you can proceed with adding it, but leveraging Magento's existing role management might be a cleaner and more maintainable solution.

"You can set up roles for specific stores and assign them to users." but how? That is what I am looking for ;)

although I understand you may want to do this on your own, I would feel guilty not to tell you it's useless as this is supposed to be already native
You need to do under System > User Role
There you can define any roles you want and give them access to only specific store under Advanced Scope configuration.
After that all you need to do is to assign the given role to any admin you want. And all of that is 100% native and meant to work with the ACL system.
I see no point to do what you have been tasked to do there, if not just for exercicing and educational purpose.

EDIT : Also, I've seen you talk about UpgradeSchema. This is the old way of doing things under magento 2.
Now you can directly edit db_schema.xml the way you want and won't require any schema / pathc migrations.

Alright, I see that the “Advanced scope” feature in role management is not available in community edition :)

It does, i'm under       "magento/product-community-edition": "2.4.6-p7",
